# Arm64 Unknown instruction during disassembly

Tags: ios, assembly, disassembly, arm64, mach-o

I'm trying to do some analysis on libraries in apple's DYLD shared cache. But ran into an instruction I don't recognize when I tried iterate through all the branch calls.

Here is an example through Ghidra,

[image: Example of instruction.]

When I force Ghidra to disassemble the instruction, it interprets it as a branch call (which I also verified manually). But the target of the branch call makes absolutely no sense, as in this case, it jumps into the middle of a function of a complelty unrelated library.

Here's what I thought of so far

- I thought it might have been a BLX instruction, but the instruction doesn't match, BLX's opcode.
- Maybe it isn't even an instruction, but instead some data in the __text section. The MachO file does have a data_in_code load command, but it says that its datasize is 0... So i'm stumped on this one, it does seem promising though.
- And lastly all of these "instructions" seem to always come after a BR instruction.

I'll add a few more examples incase it's helpful, but thanks for your help!

[image: Ex2]
[image: Ex3]
[image: Ex4]
[image: Ex5]

Edit: Here's the text version of the first example.

```
               LAB_183ad019c      XREF[1]:     183ad01f4(j)  
       183ad019c 3f 01 0c 6b     cmp        w9,w12
       183ad01a0 e2 97 9f 1a     cset       w2,hi
       183ad01a4 41 07 05 0b     add        w1,w26,w5, LSL #0x1
       183ad01a8 23 00 0e 4a     eor        w3,w1,w14
       183ad01ac e1 05 01 0a     and        w1,w15,w1, LSL #0x1
       183ad01b0 21 00 03 0b     add        w1,w1,w3
       183ad01b4 25 00 10 0b     add        w5,w1,w16
       183ad01b8 23 00 11 0b     add        w3,w1,w17
       183ad01bc 7f 00 0a 6b     cmp        w3,w10
       183ad01c0 e4 27 9f 1a     cset       w4,cc
       183ad01c4 42 00 04 4a     eor        w2,w2,w4
       183ad01c8 7f 00 0b 6b     cmp        w3,w11
       183ad01cc e3 97 9f 1a     cset       w3,hi
       183ad01d0 5f 00 00 71     cmp        w2,#0x0
       183ad01d4 82 10 83 1a     csel       w2,w4,w3,ne
       183ad01d8 53 34 00 1b     madd       w19,w2,w0,w13
       183ad01dc 4d 00 0d 0b     add        w13,w2,w13
       183ad01e0 6d db ad b8     ldrsw      x13,[x27, w13, SXTW #0x2]
       183ad01e4 ad 01 08 8b     add        x13,x13,x8
       183ad01e8 a0 01 1f d6     br         x13
       183ad01ec 3f 75 c9 95     bl         SUB_18ad2d6e8

               LAB_183ad01f0      XREF[1]:     1d2096dd8(*)  
       183ad01f0 ed 03 13 aa     mov        x13,x19
       183ad01f4 ea ff ff 17     b          LAB_183ad019c
```

Comment: Yes, it's likely data from a literal pool.

Comment: It's not reachable since it's after an unconditional `br` (unless it's possible for the destination register to be pointing at the next instruction), so it's probably data for a PC-relative load.

Comment: Please post the full function involved in this.  And do not post pictures of text!  Always post code as text instead of a picture.  Pictures are useless.

Comment: @fuz Ok, I added a text version of the first example.

Comment: @Jester can you clarify more on the literal pool, and how this data is referenced? Sorry if macho files are outside you're expertise.

Comment: It would be accessed using a PC-relative load. I don't see any such thing there however. At least on ELF there are symbols that delimit the literal pool data, [see the documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0803/b/Accessing-and-managing-symbols-with-armlink/About-mapping-symbols)

Comment: @haowang Very strange.  No literal pool load to see.

Comment: Well since I just wanted to filter these out, I can take advantage of how there always seem to be an unconditional branch before it.

Comment: Note that BLX doesn't exist on arm64. Also I had a look at a shared cache (iPhone 7 14.6) and I can't seem to find any weird `bl` after a `br`...

Comment: As a wild guess, is it possible that these "unreachable" instructions following an unconditional indirect branch are meant to influence branch prediction or speculative execution in some way?

Comment: Did you try using apple's disassembler?  Apple make their own arm silicon, so compatibility only has to flow in one direction.

Comment: @mevets The toolchain published by Apple does not support any of their proprietary bits. They must have an unpublished branch for that.